# About Daedalus (also ADA in general) delegation privacy

Tags: daedalus, privacy

I'm feeling really uncomfortable about delegation privacy. No matter how many wallets/addresses I use to separate my funds people can use https://cardanoscan.io to see which addresses are delegated into which pools.

Even though it's not solid proof for who's the owner of those addresses, exchanges and pool owners can backtrack my delegation addresses and see into which other pools have been delegated relating to that account.

I feel very disturbed about this. I know there are some ways to separate staking address from receiving address and using only the receiving address hash output for transactions, using terminals and programming but I'm not a coder and was wondering if there are any future plans to implement such privacy features in a user friendly fashion into Daedalus?

Answer (score 2):

I understand your issue, for privacy try using https://adalite.io/. They let you generate multiple Cardano Accounts that have their own stake keys. You can use this with hardwallets.

Now you can stake separately from the address you want to use for commerce.

I think this issue would be something that is down the road in the development.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response and showing an alternative wallet. I really appreciate it. But I rather stick to the official wallet and wait for an official update for it. Glad hear you think the issue would be addressed down the line, I just hope it's not way down.